# My flutter app gives me this error when I try to build can anyone help me with that?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

 Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

 Could not resolve org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.3.0.

Required by:

project :app > project :jitsi_meet

 Could not resolve org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:3.3.0.

 Could not get the resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/3.3.0/jitsi-meet-sdk-3.3.0.pom'.

 Could not HEAD 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/3.3.0/jitsi-meet-sdk-3.3.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

How to solve this error all of the code works I just go to sleep when I wake up and try to build an app it gives me an error and my network in perfect

Comment: When you build your apk, did you connected to internet?

Comment: are you going to release your app?

Comment: I am also facing same problem.have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Bintray has been shut down by JFRog: [Into the Sunset on May 1st: Bintray, GoCenter, and ChartCenter](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/). As for ExoPlayer, according to the [project's page](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer):

> ExoPlayer modules can be obtained from [the Google Maven repository](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven).

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'.
    }
}
```